# Why does Python while loop does not function properly

Tags: python, while-loop

I am running a while loop and couldn't debug the below code. Can you please help?

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

VVV = list(np.random.uniform(100, 10000, 500))
muj = [1/(VVV[j]*(1/70)/year/hour) for j in range(500)]
wj = list(np.random.uniform(1, 5, 500))
rholist = list(np.random.uniform(0, 0.02, 500))
lambdaj = [rholist[i]*muj[i]/wj[i] for i in range(500)]
tauIj = list(np.random.uniform(20/year, 40/year, 500))

for j in range(500):
    while lambdaj[j]>0.17 or lambdaj[j]<0.0005 or tauIj[j]*lambdaj[j] >= 1:
        rholist = list(np.random.uniform(0, 0.02, 500))
        lambdaj = [rholist[i]*muj[i]/wj[i] for i in range(500)]
        tauIj = list(np.random.uniform(20/year, 40/year, 500))
```

I create `VVV`, `muj`, `wj`, and `rholist` first. Then, I want to create a  `lambdaj` and `tauIj` lists satisfying that each element of `lambdaj` is bounded by `0.0005` and `0.17` and crossproduct of each element in `tauIj` and `lambdaj` is strictly less than `1`. I do not know where I am doing wrong. BTW, I intentionally resample the whole list even if one item in the list does not satisfy these conditions.

Comment: "does not function properly" - can mean a lot of things. What's the issue in this case?

Comment: Do you understand that if you have a "bad" value in let's say, item 50, and you'll resample everything, there is a chance that now you may have a "bad" value in item 17 for example, but you won't check it, because you'll continue from item 50 and forward?

Comment: @Aryerez, You very well addressed where I was doing wrong. I got the problem. Any solution suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, from what I understood from the comment, if you find a "bad" value, you need to resample everything, and then re-check from the start. You can't do that in a `for` loop in `python`, but in a `while` loop. So change it to:

```
j = 0    
while j < 500:
    if lambdaj[j]>0.17 or lambdaj[j]<0.0005 or tauIj[j]*lambdaj[j] >= 1:
        <your resamples...>
        j = -1 #To start from the beginning
    j += 1
```

But I take no responsibility over how many times you would need to resample, so it might be a good idea to `print(j)` before you restart it, so you would have an idea if your conditions are likely to exist in a 500 samples space.